# $r=a\sin \theta$ $r=a\cos \theta$ intersect at right angles

Tags: polar-coordinates

In Stewart's Calculus book, he asks:

Show that the curves  $r=a\sin \theta$, $r=a\cos \theta$  at right angles.

I do not understand the question.

It is clear that they meet for example when $\theta=\pi/4.$

Comment: The graphs actually touch twice in the plane.  You could just check the slopes of both lines at the two places the graphs intersect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already found the intersection point. It seems thsoe curves should be interpreted in *polar coordinates*. The intersecting angle is usually defined as the angle between the *tangents* of the two curves at the intersection point.

All you have to do now is calculating the tangent line of each curve at the intersection point, and calculate the angle in between them.

Comment: Many thanks, at intersection points one tangent is horizontal and the other is vertical.

Answer (score 2):

The plot shows the case where $a=2$. We have two circles, one centre $(0,\frac{a}{2})$ radius $\frac{a}{2}$ and the other centre $(\frac{a}{2},0)$ radius $\frac{a}{2}$. They intersect at the origin and at $(\frac{a}{2},\frac{a}{2})$. It is easy to check that they are orthogonal.

[image]

Comment: Not that it matters, but plotting from $0$ to $2\pi$ traces the circles twice.  That's why the curves look slightly thicker than normal.

Comment: @Bye_World Yes, good point.